# How can I get regulazation value in keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I created a NN model using keras and tensorflow like below, and I want to use L2 regularizations in my model.

But when I compute my loss, I don't know how to plus my regularization values. Can anyone help me?

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, INPUT_NODE], name='x-input')
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, OUTPUT_NODE], name='y-input')
    Layer1=Dense(INPUT_NODE,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(REGULARIZATION_RATE))(x)
    y=Dense(OUTPUT_NODE,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(REGULARIZATION_RATE))(Layer1)

loss=tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y, labels=tf.argmax(y_, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was in tensorflow, the regularization you calculate gets stored in a collection called 'regularization_losses' and since I m assuming your keras is using tensorflow in backend, you can try doing,

```html
loss =  # your loss function
reg_loss = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
total_loss = loss + reg_loss
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it doesn't work. Finally, I find a way to do it using model.losses to get the regularization loss.